# missing from the Angular 2 error: TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

**payment-details.component.ts:**

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-payment-details',
      templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./payment-details.component.css']
    })
    export class PaymentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor() { }    
      ngOnInit() {     }
    }



     import { PaymentDetailsComponent } from './Payment/payment-details/payment-details.component';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes =  [

  {path : 'payment-details', component:  PaymentDetailsComponent  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]

})


export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**in src folder tsConfig.app.Json:**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Error Message:**

> C:\src\SchoolsMadeEasy\src\app\Payment\payment-details\payment-details.component.ts
>   is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in
>   your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

I am loosely following heroes tutorial for using routing. Any ideas why my code is not compiling?

Comment: can you show whats in your tsconfig

Comment: @PrashantKumar I have edited my question

Comment: Try using below code: {
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question, but ran into this because I got a similar error message.

In my case it was caused by a case mismatch in the filename and the reference to the file in an import statement.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old post but this might help someone to resolve.

adding ["preserveSymlinks": true](http://%22preserveSymlinks%22:%20true) to angular.json did trick for me.

```js
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
              },
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "preserveSymlinks": true
          }
```

Comment: searched for hours about this. Thank you very much!

Comment: This fixed it for me even when there were no symlinks in the path to the file it said wasn't being compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your typescript file located? If it is located outside of the /src/ folder I believe tsconfig cannot find it.

Edit: Try including the following in your tsconfig file:

```
"src/**/*"
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I have tsConfig file in my src folder

Comment: Try doing what it suggests? So include something like:
`{
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ],
  "exclude" : ...
}
`

Comment: I now get an error : No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["test.ts","**/*.spec.ts"]'.